# 2002: Connection timed out while inserting data from PHP My SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, mariadb

I'm writing this PHP program that inserts a record into a table called events. The PHP code is:

```
<?php
$servername = "example.com";
$username = "dev";
$password = "some password";
$dbname = "mydb";

$dateModified = gmdate("Y-m-d h:i:s a");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die($conn -> connect_errno. " : ".$conn -> connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (ID, eventName, timeStamp, dateModified)
VALUES ('1', 'Login', 'Login', '12/12/2019',".$dateModified;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
2002 : Connection timed out
```

Interestingly, If I wrap it up in a function and try the same, It is giving this error:

```
1045 : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: First of all user is empty in the error , and then you will have to grant privileges to user @localhost in the mysql. Also where is $password?? Also there is error in SQL query.

Comment: I'm having the username set.. I replaced it with a dummy variable for sake of posting. Username and Password is set in my code.

Comment: You are missing ) after $dateModified.

Comment: the error Access denied for user ''@'localhost'  telling no user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the query.

- missing closed bracket at the end
- String **login** was given twice

See corrected version below.

```sql
$sql = "INSERT INTO events (`ID`, `eventName`, `timeStamp`, `dateModified`)
VALUES ('1', 'Login', '12/12/2019', '$dateModified')";
```

Access denied means, the user **dev** does not have **insert** privileges.